# cronjob does not execute when not logged in

Tags: cron, syslog

I have a cronjob in my crontab.

When I specify the job to be executed in 2minutes, I wait, and then I can see files created by the job, I can see the process with ps. The job takes at least 10minutes to complete.

But, if I specify the job to be executed in 2minutes, and then I log out, I come back a few minutes thereafter, and it seems that the job has not been executed (no files created, and process not in ps).

When I look to the /var/log/syslog I can see that the job 'started', but immediately (at the same second) cron tries to send a mail. Probably the mail with the result. (well, sendmail is not correctly configured but this should not be the root cause).

Do you have any idea ?

---

Here are some concrete example :  (python is the name of my machine)

I edit the crontab  using   crontab -e.
Here is the crontab :

```
user@python:~$ crontab -l
[...]
# m h  dom mon dow   command

50 9 * * * /home/user/scripts_automated/crontab1.sh
```

It should run at 9:50

Here is the content of the /var/log/syslog  :

```
[...]
Nov  6 09:48:02 python crontab[30913]: (user) BEGIN EDIT (user)
Nov  6 09:48:18 python crontab[30913]: (user) REPLACE (user)
Nov  6 09:48:18 python crontab[30913]: (user) END EDIT (user)
Nov  6 09:50:01 python CRON[30936]: (user) CMD (/home/user/scripts_automated/crontab1.sh)
Nov  6 09:50:01 python sendmail[30938]: sA68o1a4030938: from=user, size=347, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201411060850.sA68o1a4030938@python>, relay=user@localhost
[...]
```

As you can see in the log,  I edited the `crontab` at 09:48:02,   then I logged out.  I come back on the machine (with `ssh`), and the job did not produce any files it should have produced.

Here is the content of the script :

```
user@python:~$ cat scripts_automated/crontab1.sh


#  0  ------------------------------------------------------

datenow=`date +%F_%H-%M-%S`
/home/user/scripts_automated/script_1_cisco_grab.sh > /home/user/scripts_automated/crontab/run_${datenow}_.txt 2>&1 &
echo $! > /home/user/scripts_automated/crontab/pid_${datenow}.txt
ln -s /home/user/scripts_automated/crontab/pid_${datenow}.txt /home/user/scripts_automated/crontab/pid_last_run.txt
```

and no file is produced. I would at least expect the file `pid_${datenow}.txt` to exist with the pid of the background command. But nothing.
If I don't log out, then scripts executes, produces output files, `pid_${datenow}` file, and so on ...

Comment: How do you specify the job to be executed? Please give concrete examples, do edit the crontab file and change the two fields?

Comment: Could you add the script to your question?

Comment: I edited my question with a concrete example

Comment: Does the user have an encrypted home directory? If so, it will be unmounted and unavailable when logged off.

Comment: I think you got it ! Indeed, when I created the home directory, I specified to encrypt it ! Is it possible to uncrypt a user directory? Is only my user home directory encrypted, or is hte whole /home encrypted ?   how can I check that ?  many thanks for your help! you pointed it out !

Comment: @Stef You can use `mount` to see what is mounted `/home/stef` (e.g.) or `/home`. You don't need to decrypt your home directory, just copy the executable file somewhere that is not encrypted, as I indicated in my answer. Decrypting a home dir is possible, but you should make a new question for that, with details about your system (what Linux version, what encryption etc).

Comment: I rolled back your "SOLVED" edit. If one of the answers solved your issue, consider accepting it. If you have a solution that is different from all answers, then consider adding that solution as a separate answer and accept it later. Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved. Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 7):

You should put your script in a separate directory, that for sure is available while the cron job is running, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/`.

It is also good custom to write `crontab` entries like this:

```
M H * * *  test -x /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh && /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
```

so the crontab doesn't even try to execute the script if it is not available.

---

You suspected the logout being the problem, what you should have tried as well is logging out and then back in in-time for the crontab to run and then observe. That way you could have narrowed down if the logging out was the problem or the being not logged in.

Comment: I tried this. I really made a lot of tries. Even unlogging after the scripts started, and I can see that the process stoped.

Comment: It should be `&&` and not `||` I think

Comment: @Luca I think you are right

Comment: yes it should be `&&` because that would mean if-and-only-if the previous command exits successfully, then execute the next. It's opposite would be `||`, which only executes if the first failed

Answer (score 1):

The log file shows that the crontab job was fired:

```
Nov  6 09:50:01 python CRON[30936]: (user) CMD (/home/user/scripts_automated/crontab1.sh)
```

And a moment later, an email message was sent:

```
Nov  6 09:50:01 python sendmail[30938]: sA68o1a4030938: from=user, size=347, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201411060850.sA68o1a4030938@python>, relay=user@localhost
```

The next line in the log file would almost have certainly been the complementary half to this one, showing where it went.

Why the relevance of the email? CRON captures *stdout* and *stderr* from every job it fires. If either is non-empty then it sends an email message to the user's local email account containing the text it captured. In `user`'s case this will be have been to `user`'s local email account. (If you have an email subsystem configured it might then be forwarded off-site but let's assume not for now.) Local email usually gets written to the file `/var/mail/$USER` or `/var/spool/mail/$USER`. It's a text file and newer messages are simply appended, so you can use `more` or `less` or even `cat` to view the file. The last message would have been the one you wanted to read.

Looking at the script you've created, I would suspect that in your case the error message generated would have been something like this,

```
-sh: /home/user/scripts_automated/crontab1.sh: Permission denied
```

If that's the case it's because you're trying to run `crontab1.sh` as a program but you've omitted to make it executable. Fix that with `chmod a+x /home/user/scripts_automated/crontab1.sh`.

Other errors can relate to missing environment variables, including `PATH` not being set as you expect. This is because `cron` has a very restricted environment and does not use startup files such as `.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc. Another possibility is that your home directory may be encrypted when you are not logged on. In this case `cron` won't be able to find the script to execute so it can only fail. There are many questions (and answers) on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ addressing these type of issue so I won't repeat them here.

The other issue I have with your script generally is that it should start with `#!` and then a path to its interpreter. If this is `bash` you'd typically write `#!/bin/bash`, if it's `sh` you'd use `#!/bin/sh`. Starting with `#  0  ------------------------------------------------------` doesn't help the system understand how to run your script.

<sup>(Six years on, it's going to be an answer for future readers)</sup>